# Join 2 table with group query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
INVOICES TABLE
id  |   date        | Customer
1   |   2018-01-01  |    a
2   |   2018-01-01  |    b
3   |   2018-01-02  |    c
4   |   2018-01-02  |    d
5   |   2018-01-02  |    e


INVOICES_ITEMS TABLE
id  |   invoice_id  |   name       | total
1   |       1       | Billing      |  1500
2   |       2       | Billing      |  400
3   |       2       | Reconnection |  100
4   |       3       | Installation |  1000
5   |       4       | Billing      |  900
6   |       4       | Penalty      |  500
7   |       5       | Reconnection |  100
```

i have invoice_items table in my database to store all the invoice items. i have `date column` in my `Invoice Table` and `name column` in my `invoice_item table`. What i want is to  group all the data with the same name and date and get their total. I am having a hard time achieving what i want. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Expected Output:

```
    Date   | Billing | Reconnection | Installation | Penalty
2018-01-01 |  1900   |   100        |      0       |    0
2018-01-02 |  900    |   100        |      1000    |    500
```

Current Code:

```
$q = $this->db
        ->select ( "invoices.date, 
             SUM(invoices_items.total) as Billing,
             SUM(invoices_items.total) as Reconnection,
             SUM(invoices_items.total) as Installation,
             SUM(invoices_items.total) as Penalty,
        ->from("invoices")
        ->join("invoices_items", "invoices.id=invoices_items.invoice_id")
        ->group_by(array("date","name"))
        ->get();
```

Current Code Output:

```
    Date   | Billing | Reconnection | Installation | Penalty
2018-01-01 |  1900   |   1900       |      1900    |    1900
2018-01-01 |  100    |   100        |      100     |    100
2018-01-02 |  900    |   900        |      900     |    900
2018-01-02 |  100    |   100        |      100     |    100
2018-01-02 |  1000   |   1000       |      1000    |    1000
2018-01-02 |  500    |   500        |      500     |    500
```

Comment: have any error?

Comment: None. but the result is not correct, I can't achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Sum with if condition ...

```
$q = $this->db
        ->select ( "invoices.date, 
            SUM(IF(invoices_items.name='Billing',invoices_items.total, 0)) as Billing,
            SUM(IF(invoices_items.name='Reconnection',invoices_items.total, 0)) as Reconnection,
            SUM(IF(invoices_items.name='Installation',invoices_items.total, 0)) as Installation,
            SUM(IF(invoices_items.name='Penalty',invoices_items.total, 0)) as Penalty")
        ->from("invoices")
        ->join("invoices_items", "invoices.id=invoices_items.invoice_id")
        ->group_by(array("invoices.date"))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use date() in group by. You may try this. It may work

```
 $this->db
        ->select ("i.date, 
             SUM(it.total) as Billing,
             SUM(it.total) as Reconnection,
             SUM(it.total) as Installation,
             SUM(it.total) as Penalty")
        ->from("invoices i")
        ->join("invoices_items it", "i.id=it.invoice_id")
        ->group_by(['date(i.date)', 'it.name'])
        ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still cant get the result like in `expected output`